# Modify an array from indexes contained in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jax

I have an array of the shape (2,10) such as:

```py
arr = jnp.ones(shape=(2,10)) * 2
```

or

```py
[[2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
 [2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]]
```

and another array, for example `[2,4]`.

I want the second array to tell from which index the elements of `arr` should be masked. Here the result would be:

```py
[[2. 2. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
 [2. 2. 2. 2.  -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]]
```

I need to use `jax.numpy` and the answer to be vectorized and fast if possible, i.e. not using loops.

Comment: With `numpy` it's straight forward: `for i in range(2): arr[i, idx[i]:] = -1`.  Were you looking for some personal magic?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I was looking for something vectorized and fast using jax.numpy

Comment: I, and possibly others, like to see a more explicit question, one that shows what you are doing - even if it iterates as I suggest.  Don't leave the magical "vectorized" goal unstated!

Comment: I do agree. I edited my question for potential future readers.

Comment: In some quick testing, the relative speed of the loop versus the masked `where`, depends on the array shape (n,m).  Where `m` is relatively large, using `n` slices is faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a [vmapped](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/quickstart.html#auto-vectorization-with-vmap) three-term [`jnp.where`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.where.html) statement. For example:

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax

arr = jnp.ones(shape=(2,10)) * 2
idx = jnp.array([2, 4])

@jax.vmap
def f(row, ind):
  return jnp.where(jnp.arange(len(row)) < ind, row, -1)

f(arr, idx)
# DeviceArray([[ 2.,  2., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
#              [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.]], dtype=float32)
```